# Endpoint Instance cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Im new to AWS sagemaker. Im looking to deploy Jumpstart LLM model (Falcon-40b), to do that I have used ml.g5.24xlarge Notebook instance.

My question is, when I deploy that model and created a endpoint, will this create new ml.g5.24xlarge instance or use the existing notebook instance?

I tried to comeup cost using aws pricing calulcator.

Do, I need to consider only Notebook instance or add new instance for serverless endpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deploying the model to an Endpoint will create a separate instance - which will stay active until the Endpoint is deleted. When you invoke your model from the notebook, you're calling an API and the actual inference work will happen on the endpoint.

In general when using SageMaker I'd suggest keeping your notebook instances small (e.g. an `ml.t3.medium`) and use the on-demand infrastructure for heavier tasks: SageMaker Processing, Training, and Batch inference ("transform") jobs all also run on separate compute which automatically shuts down as soon as the job is completed. In cases where you do need more resources, can temporarily spin up a bigger notebook and shut it down again.